# How can I add a custom menu to my website and what file would I need to edit?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, themes

I am working out of wordpress, and I am using a plugin called a

> theme switcher

This plugin allows me to use a different theme for a mobile device. That being said, other plugins like the {theme switcher} did **NOT** save my content.

> **Example.**
>
> 1. I activated the **desktop theme** I selected for my **mobile site**, so i could make changes in the wordpress dashboard.
> 2. I edited the content (no custom code used) . I only used the wordpress appearance menu to edit this theme.
> 3. When I was done , I switch my theme back to my orignal website for my **Desktop**
> 4. All of the changes I made disappears off the mobile site, the color starts getting distorted, but when I switch my mane website back the
>      changes comeback.

That being said

Only way I knew to make a permanent edit to the files, was by going to the files directly in my file manager.

Directly in the themes folder that I chose for my mobile site.

**How can I add a menu list to a theme's file?**

Comment: May be try making changes in both themes. or check 'settings' that applies for all themes.

Comment: I have done those things, I want to know exactly how to create a menu so I can place it in the template,file, theme,etc .. I dont know where to place it  ,once I have created it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "menu include" is usually in the header.php file for your given theme. Look for something like the following:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( $args ); ?>
```

If you replace this line with something like this, it will make your menu permanent and you will not be able to edit it in "Appearance > Menus":

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/yes">Yes</a></li>
        <li><a href="/no">No</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Fair warning that any theme updates will overwrite this header.php file. If you want to keep these changes, you will have to look into [Child Themes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).

Comment: Is that an example or is that what i need to copy n paste directly..... But im using the Tempera theme... I went to header.php , didnt see that php code though..... how will that code you wrote above link to my wordpress pages and menus

Comment: Just an example. If it's not in that file, it's somewhere within their theme.|

Grasping at straws, is there a folder called "functions" or "includes"? You'll have to dig through the theme to find where the menu is being pulled in from the wordpress admin.